# Edit report in access 2013

Tags: forms, ms-access, report

I have a access form with the following code:

```
Private Sub btnRechercheModele_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptRechercheModele", acViewPreview, "reqRechercheModele"
End Sub
```

From what I understand there is a report called "rptRechercheModele". The question is how do I open it from the access interface (not from the button) so I can modify the form and where do I check the "reqRechercheModele" clause (in the access interface again) ?

Thanks

[edit] In the Report Assistant, I can see the request "reqRechercheModele" but how do I see the content of this request?

Comment: They aren't in the navigation pane under reports and queries? They could be hidden. Right-Click the nav pane header and choose "navigation options". There is a checkbox to "Show Hidden Objects". Make sure that is checked and see if you can locate the report and query. `reqRechercheModele` looks like a query name.

Comment: reqRechercheModele is in the FilterName argument - I have never used FilterName. Apparently this is just query object so open it the query designer.